# Microsoft Graph API | How to get threadID from Powershell Graph API?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

While I try this query to get the thread IDs, I could get result from graph explorer while I got error on powershell using graph API.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
    "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "ff308d27-f08b-4e53-80d6-f8634ac7d1ed",
      "date": "2019-05-17T06:31:12"
    }
  }
}
```

This is the query I tried from both environment. 
GET *https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/[groupid]/threads/[threadid]*

Why only explorer is working well but not in my powershell mode? :(

And how can I get the threadID using Powershell Command?

Comment: Found out - from API permission, I granted Mail.ReadWrite ! :)

Comment: Great! Please add an answer below, if that might be helpful for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Found solution :
From AAD with Graph API permission page, I granted Mail.ReadWrite on Delegate and User. :)